# iOS - Draw path revealing an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to draw a path revealing an image.

I managed to do this with gradients like this:

```
        CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
        CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
```

I tried to apply the same principle to draw path revealing an image like this:

```
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
        CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; <<-- I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
        CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
        CGImageRelease(imageRef), imageRef = NULL;
```

From the above code I got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the line `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `placeholder.png` in Assets?

Comment: I used it in this app before. There was no problem. @farzadshbfn

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution to my question.

I changed from

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; <<-- I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
        CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
        CGImageRelease(imageRef), imageRef = NULL;
```

to

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        [image drawInRect:rect];
```